# Including header file in header file

Tags: c++, header

I have this code in C++:

```
#ifndef MYCLASS_H
#define MYCLASS_H

#include "gspace.h"

class myclass {
    public:

    void update(gspace **);
}
```

gspace is another class defined in gspace.h. The compiler however is telling me:

```
include/myclass.h error: ‘gspace’ has not been declared|
```

Is there anything wrong in what I'm doing?

EDIT:

```
#ifndef GSPACE_H
#define GSPACE_H

#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;
class gspace
{
    public:
        gspace();
```

Comment: Is there any namespace?

Comment: Are you missing a `;` after the declaration of gspace?

Comment: @Borgleader Do you mean class gspace; {}? . Is that correct? The IDE makes the class files and I don't use them, plus it's never given an error for that...

Comment: @MyUserIsThis No I mean `class gspace {};`

Comment: @Borgleader Yes, that's what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have even declared a class named "gspace" in gspace.h I could think of two possible errors.

1) class gspace would not be in global scope i.e could be in some namespace.

2) Please check if header gaurds used in gspace not "MYCLASS_H".

Comment: Well, the class gspace is defined as:
class gspace
{ ... No namespace. As for you point 2 I don't understand it

Comment: Did it. Edited the first post.